# Awaiting .text() call on clipboardItem.getType returns pending all the time

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to paste a URL into my web app which the user has been instructed to copy.

The following code seems to be returning a promise that is pending the `.text()` completing, whereas logging `result` looks to be fine?

I would like to access `result.text().result` when the promises status is resolved, but the specific code seems to be eluding me.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
const pasteBtn = document.getElementById("btn-paste");
pasteBtn.addEventListener('click', pasteFunc);
                            
async function pasteFunc () {
                                
    console.log('Attempting Paste');
                                
    try {

        const pastetext = await navigator.clipboard.read();
        for (const item of pastetext) {
                                         
            if (!item.types.includes('text/uri-list')) {
                                            
                throw new Error('Could not see a link in the clipboard....');
                                              
            }
                                          
            await item.getType('text/uri-list').then((result) => {
                                             
                console.log ('2', result.text())

                // --> { status: 'pending'}
                // but later --> { status: 'resolved', result: 'link text we need!'} 
                                        
            });                                 
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('paste error', error);
    }
}
```

Comment: mixing async/await with Promise then usually means you're doing it wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to access result.text().result when the promises status is resolved

To access the eventual value of a promise, `await` that promise. I also recommend you don't mix `await` with `.then`. Eg:

```
const result = await item.getType('text/uri-list');
const text = await result.text();
console.log('2', text); // 'link text we need!'
```